# Linux diff command, is it discarding newlines?

Tags: diff

Does the Linux implementation if `diff -w` discard `\n`?
I don't have access to a Linux machine to check that out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-w` flag [means](https://linux.die.net/man/1/diff):

```
-w --ignore-all-space
    Ignore all white space.
```

Now, this isn't very clear becase "white space" actually includes `\n` usually. For example, the `\s` class in Perl Compatible Regular Expressions or the POSIX `[[:space:]]` both match a newline character:

```
$ printf '\n' | grep -zqP '\s' && echo yes
yes
$ printf '\n' | grep -zq '[[:space:]]' && echo yes
yes
```

However, `diff` works by comparing *lines* and lines are defined by the `\n` character (so does `grep`, actually, which is why I had to use `-z` above). Therefore, `diff` cannot take `\n` into account since a `\n` means this is a different line. So no, the `-w` option doesn't cause `diff` to discard newlines, a an empty line means the files don't match:

```
$ printf 'foo\nbar\n' > file1
$ printf 'foo\n\nbar\n' > file2
$ diff -wq  file1 file2
Files file1 and file2 differ
```

However, there is an option that does make `diff` ignore changes due to the number of lines:

```
-B --ignore-blank-lines
    Ignore changes whose lines are all blank.

$ diff -sB  file1 file2
Files file1 and file2 are identical
```

Comment: None of those options will make it treat `line1\nline2` as equivalent to `line1 line2`.